# C# Using dynamic parameter in stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic

I'm creating a stored procedure for SQL Server to call from a C# app. The stored procedure contains some dynamically created SQL this receives a parameter to execute `sp_executesql` with the query but when I run it from my C# app, I'm not get results.

When I call the procedure from SQL Server Management Studio, I get the all results.

For example: I get my table Products

```
id | Descrip
1    Pen
2    Pencil
3    Table
```

I create my stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_getproductslist]
    @idProducts varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)

    SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM Products WHERE id IN ('+@idProducts +')'

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
END
```

If I execute in SSMS:

```
EXECUTE proc_getproductslist '''1'',''2'''
```

this works! But... from the C# app this doesn't work

C# code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataTable d1 = new DataTable();

using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("cnxstring"))
{
    cn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("proc_getproductslist", cn, sqlTran);
    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    try
    {
        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@numguia", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "'''1'',''2'''";

        SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da1.SelectCommand = cmd1;
        da1.Fill(d1);
    }
    catch (SqlException exsql)
    {
        try
        {
            sqlTran.Rollback();
        }
        catch (Exception exRollback)
        {
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        cn.Close();
    }

    return d1;
}
```

When I call the stored procedure from my C# app this does not return anything.

Please I need help how to make this work.

Thanks

Comment: why aren't you using standard parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TSQL '' is escaped '.  Not so in C#.  And the first and last ' denote the string literal.  In C# " starts and ends the string literal.

So

```
cmd1.Parameters.Add("@numguia", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "'''1'',''2'''";
```

Should be

```
cmd1.Parameters.Add("@numguia", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "'1','2'";
```

or since it appears to be a list of ints

```
cmd1.Parameters.Add("@numguia", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "1,2";
```

EG

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp10
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var con = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;database=tempdb;integrated security=true"))
            {
                con.Open();

                var ddl = new SqlCommand(@"
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_getproductslist]
    @idProducts varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)

    SET @SQL = 'SELECT ''success'' result WHERE ''1'' IN ('+@idProducts +')'

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
END
", con);
                ddl.ExecuteNonQuery();

                var cmd = new SqlCommand("proc_getproductslist", con);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@idProducts", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "'''1'',''2'''";


                var result = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar() ;
                Console.WriteLine(result??"null");

                cmd.Parameters["@idProducts"].Value = "'1','2'";
                result = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                Console.WriteLine(result??null);

                Console.ReadKey();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

outputs

```
null
success
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use table valued paramters, this is pretty much exactly what they were designed for...

First create your type:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.ListOfInt AS TABLE (Value INT NOT NULL);
```

Then your procedure is as simple as

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_getproductslist]  @idProducts dbo.ListOfInt READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  * 
    FROM    Products 
    WHERE   id IN (SELECT Value FROM @idProducts);

END
```

No Dynamic SQL required. As a quick aside, [it is not good idea to use `SELECT *` in production code](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list).

Finally, to call your procedure (removing try/catch for brevity)

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataTable d1 = new DataTable();

//Set the IDs you wish to pass
DataTable dtParam = new DataTable();
dtParam.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(int));
dtParam.Rows.Add(1);
dtParam.Rows.Add(2);


using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("cnxstring"))
using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("proc_getproductslist", cn, sqlTran))
{
    cn.Open();
    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    //Create and add the parameter
    var tableParam = new SqlParameter("@numguia", SqlDbType.Structured);
    tableParam.Value = dtParam;
    tableParam.TypeName = "dbo.ListOfInt";
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(tableParam);

    SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
    da1.Fill(d1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your C# code parameter's names of the Select command with `CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure` must match the names of the parameters defined in the Sql code. Try

```
   cmd1.Parameters.Add("@idProducts", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "1,2";
```