# How to pass SqlCommand parameter dynamically using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core

I have created a class, in which I am trying to pass query and return the data in a `DataTable`, but I am unable to pass a parameter to the `SqlCommand`.

My attempt:

```
OpenSqlConnection();

SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(inputQuery, sqlConnection);
sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("", "");

sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
da.Fill(dtResult);

CloseSqlConnection();

return dtResult;
```

In the above code, I am passing `SqlCommand` as an input query.

How I am calling the above function.

```
stdFetchDt = new DBManager().GetRecordsByQuery("storedprocedurename");

stdDrop.DataSource = stdFetchDt;
stdDrop.DataBind();
```

Here `DBManager` is the class name and `GetRecordsByQuery` is the method name.

But I'm not able to pass value for `sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("", "");`.

**My problem**: I am unable to pass value in `sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("", "");`, because number of value may be multiple.

Please help me with this.

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: then, how can I pass object and value into it?

Comment: I'm confused: what is the name and data type of the parameter, and what value do you want to pass? `""` is not a valid parameter name. Also there are many other issues with your code: `OpenSqlConnection` and `CloseSqlConnection` is just wrong, you should have the connection in a `using`, as well as the adapter and command. You shouldn't call `ExecuteNonQuery` if you want a result, the adapter will sort out execution. If you want to send multiple values you should use a Table Valued Parameter, for example see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66065761/

Comment: can this question help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46101756/c-sharp-using-dynamic-parameter-in-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Created a class and passing OBJECT & VALUE using List argument.

```
 public DataTable GetRecordsByQuery(string inputQuery, List<string> objectInput, List<string> valInput)
```

Here in **inputQuery** String, I am passing name of stored procedure and in ***objectInput*** passing object and in ***valInput*** passing its value.

Answer (score 0):

You can send your parameter string with values combined with ',' in C# and then separate theme in the stored procedure :

```
DECLARE @tags NVARCHAR(400) = 'clothing,road,,touring,bike'  

SELECT value  
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@tags, ',')
```

Comment: No, Its not working.